# Is $x_n =\sqrt{n} (\sqrt{n+1}− \sqrt{n})$ , $n \ge 1$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$$x_n =\sqrt{n} (\sqrt{n+1}− \sqrt{n}) ,\quad n \ge 1$$

My work is:

First i analyzed the convergence of this sequence in 2 parts:

a) $\lim \sqrt{n+1}− \sqrt{n} = \lim \frac{(\sqrt{n+1}− \sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} = \lim \frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} = \lim \frac{1}{ \infty} = 0$ when $n  \rightarrow \infty$.

But now how can I conclude that $\lim_{n  \rightarrow \infty}x_n = 0$

Comment: You forgot to multiply by $\sqrt{n}$. The limit should be $1/2$.

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A basic trick you should learn is that:

$$\sqrt{n+1}- \sqrt{n} = \frac{(\sqrt{n+1}- \sqrt{n}) \cdot (\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n})}{1 \cdot (\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} $$

Using that yields:

$$x_n=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1\right)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + 1}$$

Hence:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x_n = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: can you check my answer bot.. is it correct?

Comment: @kitkat4.4 : Look at my edit to your answer.  You wrote $lim_{x\to\infty} x_n$.  I changed it to $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} x_n$.  Using \lim instead of lim not only prevents italicization, but also (when in a "displayed" setting, as opposed to an "inline" setting) affects the position of the subscript and affects spacing in expressions like $a\lim b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Knight Your answer is correct, but using the squeeze theorem might be an overkill, to say the least.

@ MichaelHardy Thanks, I'll remember that.

Comment: ok. Really thanks

Answer (score 4):

Simply

$$x_n=\sqrt n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1\right)}$$
now cancel and pass to the limit.

Answer (score 4):

Is it correct this?

$\begin{align}
x_n
&=\sqrt{n} (\sqrt{n+1}− \sqrt{n})\\
&=\sqrt{n} (\sqrt{n+1}− \sqrt{n})\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n}}\\
&=\sqrt{n} \dfrac{(\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}− \sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n}}\\
&=\sqrt{n} \dfrac{(n+1)-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n}}\\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n}}\\
\end{align}
$

so
$x_n
> \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n+1}}
$
and
$x_n
< \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}
=\dfrac12
$.

Doing the same thing to bound
the difference between these two bounds,

$\begin{align}
\dfrac12-\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n+1}}
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n+1}}\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n}}\\
&=\dfrac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n})}{2\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n})}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n})}\\
&<\dfrac{1}{4n}\\
\end{align}
$

so
$\dfrac12 -\dfrac1{{4n}}
< x_n < \dfrac12$
so $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \dfrac12$.

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little sloppy, but I'm not sure how to clean it up at the moment, however its different so I thought of sharing.

$$x_{n+m} - x_n = \sqrt{n+m}\sqrt{n+m+1} - \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1} - m ≈(n+m)-n-m=0$$

Because for large enough $n$ there is little difference between $\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n+1}$ .  And every Cauchy Sequence is convergent.

Comment: I like this approach a lot. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

What can you say about the limit of $\sqrt{n}/(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n})?$

Answer (score 0):

Just to try something different:

$$\sqrt n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n) =
\sqrt n \sqrt n(\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-\sqrt 1)=
n(\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1)=
\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1}{\frac1n}$$

If we look at the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ at the point $1$ we see that
$$f'(1)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(1+t)-f(1)}t = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+t}-1}t.$$
But we know that $f'(x)=(\sqrt{x})'=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$, hence $f'(1)=\frac12$
and 
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+t}-1}t = \frac12.$$

Now if $n\to\infty$ then $\frac1n\to0^+$, so the above equation yields
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1}{\frac1n} = \frac12.$$

---

In fact this answer is "bad" in the sense that when you are being taught about limits of sequences you probably have not learned about derivatives yet. And even if you learned about derivatives, this is probably the limit that was used to derive the derivative of $\sqrt x$.

But I thought that it is at least interesting to mention the connection between this question and derivatives. (Other useful answers have been given already. And you might be reminded of this later, when you learn about derivatives.)